# Node.JS runs into SSL trust issue while NPM executes

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm, ssl-certificate

We have NPM and Node bundled installed for a user. My company does SSL Decryption, and I was able to work with my user to ignore SSL issues for NPM using the `.npmrc` file. However, for Node, the issue is still persistent. When running `npm i` in the project, we still get Node SSL issues.

We tried to run `node --use-openssl-ca` in PowerShell / Visual Studio in the terminal portion at the bottom (this is Windows). But the command opens Node and gives an area to type with a 'caret' `>`. It's not taking the command. Where should this be entered as a global variable to ignore it? (Our system proxy will continue to do SSL decryption and block malicious packages).

Here is a [a screenshot for the issue in PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfhUQ.png).

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question and fix the grammar? You can use backticks to indicate code (or use the GUI). Running a spell checker and fixing the capitalization would also be nice. [so] tries to be a knowledge base and questions and answers are expected to be well formatted. If you have trouble formatting then just reply to this comment.

Comment: I've edited your question, please take a look at the timeline [to see the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78110702/timeline). I've also tried to give the question a better title, if it doesn't fit hit [edit].

Comment: This is not really a programming or development issue, but: instead of replacing the truststore with _option_ `--use-openssl-ca` you can ADD TO it with [_env var_ `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/cli.html#node_extra_ca_certsfile).